# Program needs to loop X amount of times, will only run once no matter the input. No errors thrown

Tags: java

Program needs to run the Dice.java however many times the user enters, will only run once and throws no errors. I also can't prove anything, but it feels like the output has a pattern to it.

Tried a little bit of everything.

DiceGame1.java - Acts as a main loop, takes how many dice the user wants to roll at once, and handles the main loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiceGame1
{
    public static int mainloop;
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        mainloop = 0;
        Scanner OBJ_USERINPUT = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many dice to roll: ");
        int VAR_HOWMANY = OBJ_USERINPUT.nextInt();
        while (mainloop < 1)
        {
            //Create a for loop that will run X amount of times
            for(int i =0; i< VAR_HOWMANY; i++)
            {
                Dice.RollDie();
                RunAgain.RunAgain();
            }
        }
}

}
```

Dice.java - Intended to do the actual dirty work of rolling the die, which will then hand back off to DiceGame1.java to let it know to run again.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Dice 
{
    public static void RollDie()
    {
        Random DIEROLL = new Random();
        //the integer randomInteger equals whatever the DIEROLL object generates.
        int randomInteger = DIEROLL.nextInt(6);
        //Add one to the integer randomInteger so 0 doesn't appear
        randomInteger = randomInteger+1;
        // Prints out the generated number
        switch (randomInteger)
        {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("1");
        case 2:
            System.out.println("2");
        case 3:
            System.out.println("3");
        case 4:
            System.out.println("4");
        case 5:
            System.out.println("5");
        case 6:
            System.out.println("6");
        }
    }
}
```

RunAgain.java - Intended to let DieGame1.java how long to run the endless loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RunAgain 
{
    public static void RunAgain()
    {
        String userinput;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Run again? Y/N: ");
        userinput = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (userinput.equals ("Y"))
        {
        System.out.println("======================================");
        }
        else
        {
            keyboard.close();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In file DiceGame1.java, in this block of code,

```
//Create a for loop that will run X amount of times
for(int i =0; i< VAR_HOWMANY; i++)
{
   Dice.RollDie();
   RunAgain.RunAgain();
}
```

shouldn't `RunAgain.RunAgain()` be called outside of you for loop, in order to get the behavior you want.

Hence, it should be something like this,

```
//Create a for loop that will run X amount of times
for(int i =0; i< VAR_HOWMANY; i++)
{
   Dice.RollDie();
}
RunAgain.RunAgain();
```

EDIT: also modify you switch to something like this:

```
 // Prints out the generated number
        switch (randomInteger)
        {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("1");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("2");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("3");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("4");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("5");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("6");
            break;
        }
```

Comment: he also didn't use break after using case
even though the switch statment is not necessary

Comment: correct. @Dave you will need to break in each case of your case statement. Look at my edited answer. I have tested and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling RunAgain() in the wrong location and you didn't used `break` after every use of `case` in your switch statment
here it is working:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class DiceGame1
{
    public static int mainloop;
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        mainloop = 0;
        Scanner OBJ_USERINPUT = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many dice to roll: ");
        int VAR_HOWMANY = Integer.parseInt(OBJ_USERINPUT.nextLine());
        while (mainloop < 1)
        {
            //Create a for loop that will run X amount of times
            for(int i =0; i < VAR_HOWMANY; i++)
            {
                Dice.RollDie();
            }
            RunAgain.RunAgain();
        }
    }
}
class Dice
{
    public static void RollDie()
    {
        Random DIEROLL = new Random();
        //the integer randomInteger equals whatever the DIEROLL object generates.
        int randomInteger = DIEROLL.nextInt(6);
        //Add one to the integer randomInteger so 0 doesn't appear
        randomInteger = randomInteger+1;
        // Prints out the generated number
        switch (randomInteger)
        {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("1");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("2");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("3");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("4");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("5");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("6");
                break;
        }
    }
}
class RunAgain
{
    public static void RunAgain()
    {
        String userinput;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Run again? Y/N: ");
        userinput = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println(userinput);
        if (userinput.equalsIgnoreCase ("Y"))
        {
            System.out.println("======================================");
        }
        else
        {
            keyboard.close();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't entirely fix it though, when you accept to run again, it will roll however many dice you entered originally every time. It needs to prompt every time.